# Summary data using CSV file

Tags: csv, awk

Is there the possibility to improve the code below?

I am sure the result I got can be achieved with shorter code.

#### Code

```
awk -F, '{a[$2$7]+=$4}{b[$2$7]+=$5}{c[$2$7]+=$6}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i],b[i],c[i]}' tmp3 | sort -t, -k1n |
awk 'BEGIN{
print ("\tCODE-1T     COD-Area   CODE-1      CODE-S       CODE-T")
printf ("\t------------------------------------------------------------\n")
}
{
sum2 += $2;
sum3 += $3;
sum4 += $4;
sum5 = sum2 + sum3 + sum4;
printf ("\t%9s%10s%12s%12d%16d\n",substr($0,1,9),substr($0,10,5),$2,$3,$4)
}
END {
printf ("\t------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
printf ("\tTotal:\t%23d\t%11d\t%11d\t%4d\n",sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5)
printf ("\t------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
}'
```

#### Input

```
032118,333000004,3213,11,10,142,SS/RR
032118,333000004,3214,11,0,42,AS/RR
032118,333000004,3215,11,0,761,AS/RR
032118,333000005,3216,7,2,762,SS/RR
032118,333000005,3217,6,2,876,SS/RR
032118,333000005,3218,6,0,876,ST/RR
032118,333000005,3222,5,3,258,ST/RR
032118,333000006,3223,5,3,258,ST/RR
032118,333000006,3224,4,4,870,SS/RR
032118,333000006,3225,3,5,870,SS/RR
032118,333000007,3226,3,34,876,SX/RR
032118,333000007,3227,2,55,876,SS/RR
032218,333000007,3208,2,4,36,SS/RR
032218,333000007,3209,1,3,879,ST/RR
032218,333000007,3210,2,2,803,ST/RR
```

#### Output

```
CODE-1T     COD-Area     CODE-1      CODE-S       CODE-T
------------------------------------------------------------
333000004     AS/RR          22           0             803
333000004     SS/RR          11          10             142
333000005     SS/RR          13           4            1638
333000005     ST/RR          11           3            1134
333000006     SS/RR           7           9            1740
333000006     ST/RR           5           3             258
333000007     SS/RR           4          59             912
333000007     ST/RR           3           5            1682
333000007     SX/RR           3          34             876
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total:                       79         127        9185 9391
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```